# How to manage/rotate/delete mesos logs

Tags: linux, logging, docker, mesos, logrotate

I start mesos master container with the following command:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm \
    -e MESOS_HOSTNAME={{ ansible_hostname }} \
    -e MESOS_IP={{mesos.external_ip}} \
    -e MESOS_QUORUM={{mesos.quorum}} \
    -e MESOS_ZK={{mesos.zk}} \
    -e MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos -v /var/log/mesos:/var/log/mesos \
    -e MESOS_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/mesos -v {{mesos_work_dir}}:/var/lib/mesos \
    --name mesos-master --net host {{docker.master}}
```

And I get a huge amount of mesos logs:
[mesos logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJEeE.png)

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     60 Apr 19 17:14 mesos-master.INFO -> mesos-master.vdorct1.invalid-user.log.INFO.20170419-141458.6
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  23983 Apr 19 16:46 mesos-master.vdorct1.invalid-user.log.INFO.20170419-134210.6
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  48678 Apr 19 17:14 mesos-master.vdorct1.invalid-user.log.INFO.20170419-135536.6
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   6595 Apr 19 17:14 mesos-master.vdorct1.invalid-user.log.INFO.20170419-141436.6
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   8240 Apr 19 17:14 mesos-master.vdorct1.invalid-user.log.INFO.20170419-141444.6
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 122324 Apr 19 18:14 mesos-master.vdorct1.invalid-user.log.INFO.20170419-141458.6
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    253 Apr 19 16:42 mesos-master.vdorct1.invalid-user.log.WARNING.20170419-134210.
```

I need to manage this logs defining how many files to keep and/or for how many days to keep logs.
I can reach it using bash + cron. But this is not acceptable because of company policy: I have to use linux tools.

I tried to configure logrotate. But it is not usable only for deleting files: it can delete only rotated files or all files.

May be I can force mesos write logs in a single file: for example only

```
mesos-master.vdorct1.invalid-user.log.INFO
```

instead of

```
mesos-master.vdorct1.invalid-user.log.INFO.20170419-134210.6 
mesos-master.vdorct1.invalid-user.log.INFO.20170419-135536.6 
...
```

In that case I could configure logrotate.

So the question is: how I can automatically clean mesos logs using standart linux tools? Or how I can force mesos to write logs in single files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this can be implemented using logrotate with olddir parameter:

```
/var/log/mesos/*.*.* {
 olddir /var/log/mesos/backup
 maxsize 2000k
 daily
 maxage 7
 copytruncate
 postrotate
 find  /var/log/mesos /var/log/mesos/backup -mtime +7 -delete
 endscript
}
```

It is necessary for folder from olddir parameter have been created before logrotate run.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this in /var/log/mesos:

```
find /var/log/mesos -mtime +7 -name '*log.INFO.*' | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm
```

Adjust to match INFO|WARNING|ERROR, etc